# when I give long number as parameter after assigning it value it give error, but when I take input from scanner it shows result why is it so?

Tags: java

I was solving Prime factor for a given number , when I tried a program using long data type as the parameter to a method and calling it in the main method after assigning the value to the parameter in main method it gives me error , but when I tried the same program using scanner for taking input from the console for the passing the long data type as parameter it displays result.why is this so ? in both the cases I am using the same number;
Assigning the vale to the parameter in the main method it self it show error
Main.java:42: error: integer number too large: 600851475143
long n =600851475143 ;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class primeFactors
{
        public static void primeFactors(long n) 
    { 
        while (n%2==0) 
        { 
            System.out.print(2 + " "); 
            n /= 2; 
        } 

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i+= 2) 
        { 
            
        while(n%i == 0) 
            { 
                System.out.print(i + " "); 
                n /= i; 
            } 
        } 
        if (n > 2) 
            System.out.print(n); 
    } 

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
        long n =600851475143 ; 
        primeFactors(n); 
    } 
}
```

using scanner Class for passing the input to the method. scanner input is 600851475143.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class primefactors
{
        public static void primeFactors(long n) 
    { 
        while (n%2==0) 
        { 
            System.out.print(2 + " "); 
            n /= 2; 
        } 

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i+= 2) 
        { 
            
        while(n%i == 0) 
            { 
                System.out.print(i + " "); 
                n /= i; 
            } 
        } 

        if (n > 2) 
            System.out.print(n); 
    } 

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
        long n;
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=s1.nextLong();
        primeFactors(n); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: All long values must terminate with l for example n=10l;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to an `L` at the end of a `long`! I copied an pasted your code with the `L` at the end and it worked!